# Incorrect result in CAPTCHA check using PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm going to have a CAPTCHA in my form, and submit if the CAPTCHA is entered correctly. I'm using jQuery AJAX to send entered code for match check. But I get same the result in jQuery whether the CAPTCHA entered is correct or not.

How can I solve this problem and get the correct result in CAPTCHA check?

Here is my code, both PHP and jQuery:

PHP (generateimage.php):

```
header('Content-type:image/jpeg');
$text = rand(100000, 999999);

...

if (isset($_POST['check_capcha'])) {
  $check =$_POST['check_capcha'];
  if ($check == $text) {
    echo true;
  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
var check_capcha = $("#human_check_sub").val();
check_capcha = parseInt(check_capcha);
$.post("../php/generateimage.php", {check_capcha:check_capcha}, function(data) {
  if (data) {
    //$.post("../php/core.php");
    alert("ok sub");
  } else {
    $("#img_cap_sub").attr("src", "../php/generateimage.php");
    $("#caution_sub").html('<span>Capcha entered incorrect.try again</span>');
  }
});
```

Comment: what do you expect the return value to be in the `data` variable?

Comment: Unless I'm reading that wrong, you're generating a new random value for EVERY request on that script, which means your captcha is impossible to EVER get right, unless by chance the user enters the random value that'll be generated when the attempt is submitted. You need to generate **ONE** random value and store it somewhere on the server so the user has at least a CHANCE of getting it right.

Comment: Have your tried `if(data=="true")` ?

Comment: i want to return true if match and false otherwise

Comment: Have you entered your captcha value to a session or something?

Comment: no i didn't used session

Comment: Good edits Random Human, was going to do this one `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to put the first check_captcha in quotes in your $.post call:

```
 $.post("../php/generateimage.php",{"check_capcha":check_capcha},function(data){
```

If you think about it JS would use the value of check_captcha for both the key and the value so your php page might not be picking up on it.

EDIT: sorry didnt see Marc B's comment above, i would have to agree with him, you should generate a single value, save it somewhere persistant across requests (a session) and then reference that number, otherwise two random numbers will be generated and shouldn't match (that would be pretty bad if they did)

- Ken

Comment: ajax request variables does not have problem , problem is in returned data by ajax;

Comment: what is the result you are getting? always true or always false?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you generate a new capcha for every ajax request, including when validating an attempt. When you are doing a verification check rather than generating a new image skip the rand call. When generating it store the correct value in a session variable or something to check against when you pass the `check_capcha` parameter with the attempted answer.

Currently your if statements will almost certainly return false

something like

```
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_REQUEST['check_capcha']))
    {
        $_SESSION['correct'] = rand(100000, 999999);
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        if($check == $_SESSION['correct'])
        {
            echo true ;
        }
    }
```